# Metodo insertar en un árbol binario

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un árbol binario pero tengo problemas en estos dos métodos me marca errores, me parece que el problema esta en indicarle si se inserta en izquierdo o en derecho, (lo que intente esta comentado). El método "poner" es auxiliar para que funcione "insertar" y el método "insertar" tiene que insertar el elemento al nodo y los ordena si es menor va a la izquierda y si es menor va la derecha . El error me aparece cuando copilo el programa, ya anexe las lineas donde me dice que hay error.

```
     public void poner (Nodo<E> n, E elemento){
         if(n != null){
             if (n.elemento.compareTo(elemento) > 0){ //error
                 if (n.izquierdo != null);
                 insertar(elemento);//error
             }else{
                 n.izquierdo = new Nodo <> (elemento);
             }
         }
         if (n.elemento.compareTo(elemento) < 0){
             if (n.derecho != null){
                 insertar(elemento);
             }else{
                 n.derecho = new Nodo <> (elemento);
             }
         }
     }


     public void insertar (E elemento){
      //   insertar(elemento,raiz);
         if (raiz == null){
             raiz = new Nodo <> (elemento);
             return;
         }
         if (raiz.elemento.compareTo(elemento) < 0){
             if (raiz.derecho != null){
                 poner (raiz.derecho, elemento);
             }else{
                 raiz.derecho = new Nodo <> (elemento);
             }
             return;
         }
         if (raiz.elemento.compareTo(elemento) > 0){
             if (raiz.izquierdo != null){
                 poner (raiz.izquierdo, elemento);//error
             }else{
                 raiz.izquierdo = new Nodo <> (elemento);
             }
         }
         if (raiz.elemento.compareTo(elemento) == 0){
             return ;
         }
     }

 //  private void insertar(E elemento, Nodo<E> raiz) {
   //     return;
   // }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué quieres hacer con cada método y qué errores te estás encontrando? La relación entre los métodos `poner` e `insertar` no acabo de entenderla...

Comment: "me marca errores", ¿Cuales son estos?, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: Lo que veo en void Poner es que: - No consideras si el arbol esta vacio - Si n==null no entra en el primer if, pero en el segundo el pedis element a null - Y lo que me llama la atencion es que trabajes con Nodo y no con Position